# auto installing dropbox daemon(dropboxd) with profile signed in automatically script issue

Tags: linux, scripting, profile, dropbox

I am trying to install dropbox automatically in my server auto-install script so when I spawn a new VPS instance I'm able to have dropbox installed and have the credentials already inputed via the auto-install script for my VPS instance.

I know dropbox daemon dropboxd, stores profile/credential information in ~/.dropbox, however I've tried zipping/taring the folder and all its contents but it never worked when I would remove the .dropbox folder then unzip or untar the saved profile. When running dropboxd it would say the first-time-install message of 'This computer isn't linked to any Dropbox account...Please visit https://www.dropbox.com/cli_link?host_id=...'

How do I extract the profile information from my system so I can replicate it across new server instances that will be using the same dropbox account for syncing?

Also a note: I have tried dropbox uploader scripts but they don't have the sync feature where they can watch for changes in the background which I need for easy updates. trying to avoid setting up a messy cronjob when I can just use the dropbox daemon that was built for syncing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from my research that it cannot be done without some very extensive coding. There needs to be some sort of macro or api system setup which interacts with dropbox's site to add each new dropbox client (server) to the list of allowed clients on the dropbox account in order for you to install the daemon. What happens is the daemon runs and then gives you a URL which you have to copy paste to your browser for client verification. This needs to only happen once. If someone was able to listen in on the install script and grab the unique URL that gets generated, then you'd be able to script something that can login to your dropbox account and do the verification for you. However I'm not that skilled with my scripting.

There is a dropbox script which allows you to upload and download files from your dropbox account(https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader), but does not install the dropbox client on the server, which if you're looking for a solution that allows you to auto sync files from your servers, you have to manually install the dropbox daemon due to the verification process of each new client you add to your dropbox account.